# How to do "if variable a has pattern 'abc' do x, otherwise do y" (in 1 line)

Tags: bash

I want to set an alias depending on an environmental variable pattern match in 1 line.

I am trying:

```
[[$HOSTNAME =~ 'q20' ]] && alias a='cd ~/a1' || alias a='cd ~/a99'
```

but I get `-bash: [[uscamwebq20.boston.zipcar.com: command not found`

I also tried:

```
$ [ -z $HOSTNAME =~ q20 ] && alias a='cd ~/a1' || alias a1='cd ~/a99'
```

but I get `-bash: [: too many arguments`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the first form but you need to put a whitespace after `[[`. See:

```
$ type [[
[[ is a shell keyword

$ help [[
[[ ... ]]: [[ expression ]]
    Execute conditional command.
```

So your command should look like this:

```
[[ $HOSTNAME =~ 'q20' ]] && alias a='cd ~/a1' || alias a='cd ~/a99'
```

Answer (score 7):

```
case $HOSTNAME in (*q20*) alias a='cd ~/a1';; (*) alias a='cd ~/a99'; esac
```

You're getting an error, because spaces are missing after `[[` and because `-z` is to test if a particular string is empty. `[[` is a non-standard feature, how it behaves depends on the version of `bash`. The `case` structure is POSIX and as written will work in any POSIX shell and any version of `bash`.

More generally, it's also better to stay away from things like `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` as it generally doesn't not do what you want if `cmd2` fails.

Also, I don't see the point in putting it all on one line. That's something that's going to go to some rc file, right? Then it will be a lot more legible if on several lines.

```
case $HOSTNAME in
  (*q20*) alias a='cd ~/a1';;
      (*) alias a='cd ~/a99'
esac
```

is more legible and portable than:

```
if [[ $HOSTNAME =~ q20 ]]; then
  alias a='cd ~/a1'
else
  alias a='cd ~/a99'
fi
```

itself more legible (and more correct) than:

```
[[ $HOSTNAME =~ q20 ]] &&
  alias a='cd ~/a1' ||
  alias a='cd ~/a99'
```

itself more legible than

```
[[ $HOSTNAME =~ q20 ]] && alias a='cd ~/a1' || alias a='cd ~/a99'
```

Comment: Thanks!  Definitely an opinion thing that probably relates to experience level and also just plain preferences.  5 years ago I would have preferred `if then`, now I prefer the `&&` `||` for my (yes) .bashrc file.  Using such teniques in several places means that my file is now 28 lines long instead of close to 100 and fits on 1 screen which is my preference for readability as I am very visual.

Comment: +1 for a good answer for others though ;)